# jQuery: how to find if radio buttons whose ids are dynamically generated is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The item id is not know before hand. We get to know that only at run time.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)  
     {  
         ...  
           <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Agree") Agree
                 <br />
                 @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Disagree") Disagree
                 <br />
                 @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Neither") Neither  
             </td>
         </tr>
     }

<div>
     <textarea rows="5" cols="75" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
</div>

<p>
     <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</p>
```

This is my script where I want to check if the radio buttons have been checked.
If they are, then I want to allow the user to proceed.
If not, I just want to display an alert saying that they haven't made a choice.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {  
            var isValid = true;
            if ($.trim($("#comments").val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
            }
            if (isValid == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Please explain your choices in the textbox provided.');
            }
        });
    });       
</script>
```

How do I modify the above script to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each row can have radio group, I think you can

```
<tr class="choice">
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Agree") Agree
        <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Disagree") Disagree
        <br />
        @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Neither") Neither  
    </td>
</tr>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
        var isValid = true;
        if ($.trim($("#comments").val()) == '') {
            alert('Please explain your choices in the textbox provided.');
            isValid = false;
        }
        if ($('tr.choice').not(':has(:radio:checked)').length) {
            alert('Please select an option.');
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (isValid == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2osxjwtf/)

Comment: I would assume the radio buttons exist per table row `tr`, and validation should check against each `tr`

Comment: @Neverever yes... missed the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Give them a class name. Note if the input name matches you can only select one.

Assuming they do not, using the class name you will be able to check them without knowing their id.

```
if($('.myRadioButtonClassName').is(':checked')){
  console.log($('.myRadioButtonClassName'):checked').val());
}
```